# How to match observations that are within +/- 5 of each other in R?

Tags: r, string-matching

Say I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
dat <- data.frame("firstName" = c("John", "John", "Mary", "Bob", "Mary", "Bob"), "age"= c(21, 24, 35, 30, 20, 27))
```

I want to create a third variable `dat$id` that assign the same number if an observation's age is within +/- 5 years of another observation and has the same firstName. So the dataframe will look like this:

```
dat <- data.frame("firstName" = c("John", "John", "Mary", "Bob", "Mary", "Bob"), "age"= c(21, 24, 35, 30, 20, 27), "id"= c(1,1,2,3,4,3))
```

I have a very large dataset of names and ages and would like to find a more automated way of assigning id's. I considered creating age bins for every 5 years from age 20, but this will not match observations who are in different bins, but still within 5 years of age.

Comment: Are this grouped by 'firstName'

Comment: I would like to assign the same id to observations with the same firstName and that are within +/- 5 of age. They aren't currently grouped by firstName.

Comment: What should happen if there was one more entry for John with age = 29 should it match both the other John's or only the second ?

Comment: What if you have additional obs. that contain the same first names but the difference is within the range for some but not all?  e.g, John1 is within 5 of John2 and John2 is within 5 of John3 but John1 is not within 5 of John3.  If you think you actually have unique Johns, then you may need to classify the names uniquely at first and then reclassify after you've done the range test.

Comment: I want to make the assumption that if 2 or more observations have the same firstName and have an age within +/- 5, they are the same observation and will be assigned the same id.I would be making up an id, starting from 1 to the number of "matches". @Chuck P if there are 2 John's with age = 29, it will match both the John's.

Comment: @SteveM that is really good point. The data I have actually includes multiple variables of firstName, lastName, race, and nickName  and I have been able to match observations for different string-matching criteria (e.g. firstName, lastName, and race match; firstName first letter, lastName and race match). However, I am unsure how to match based on a range of the age variable. These additional name variables help to uniquely identify observations, but some "unique" observations may actually be the same and have inaccurate age values assigned.

Comment: @IanCampbell this is more representative of my dataset, with all the variables:
```dat <- data.frame("firstName" = c("John", "John", "Mary", "Bob", "Mary", "Bob"), "age"= c(21, 24, 35, 30, 20, 27), "race" = c(1,1,3,3,4,4), "lastName" = c("Smith", "Smith", "John", "L", "Smith", "L"), "nickName" = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A"))```

Comment: what would be the desired output for `data.frame(firstName=c("Cath", "Cath", "Cath"), age=c(10,15,20))`? should these be in 1 group?

Answer (score 1):

**1) sqldf/igraph** Match each row to those rows having the same name, an age within 5 and the row is not itself.  If there is no such match then match the row to itself so that all rows are accounted for.  The rows and their matches can then be turned into an edgelist and subsequently an igraph, g.  Find the connected components of and assign the membership ids to the rows of the original data frame.

In the example data each connected component is size 1 or 2 but this approach can handle any size and not just those.

```
library(igraph)
library(sqldf)

s <- sqldf("select a.rowid, a.*, b.rowid as match 
  from dat a left join dat b
    on a.firstname = b.firstname and 
      abs(a.age - b.age) < 5 and
      a.rowid != b.rowid")
e <- cbind(s$rowid, s$match) # edgelist
e[is.na(s$match), 2] <- e[is.na(s$match), 1]  
g <- graph_from_edgelist(e)
transform(dat, id = components(g)$membership)
```

giving:

```
  firstName age id
1      John  21  1
2      John  24  1
3      Mary  35  2
4       Bob  30  3
5      Mary  20  4
6       Bob  27  3
```

We can visualize the graph like this:

```
plot(g)
```

(continued after graph)

[image: screenshot]

**2) Base R** This solution is motivated, in part, by the other solutions but  has significant advantages in that it only uses base R, only 2 lines of code, like (1) also handles connected components of any size, produces the correct answer and is fully vectorized.  It works by sorting the data and then pulling forward the id or generating a new one depending on the condition shown.

```
o <- with(dat, order(firstName, age))
transform(dat[o,], id = cumsum(c(1, diff(xtfrm(firstName)) | diff(age) > 5)))
```

giving:

```
  firstName age id
6       Bob  27  1
4       Bob  30  1
1      John  21  2
2      John  24  2
5      Mary  20  3
3      Mary  35  4
```

Comment: Added base solution.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional packages

```
dat <- data.frame("firstName" = c("John", "John", "Mary", "Bob", "Mary", "Bob"), "age"= c(21, 24, 35, 30, 20, 27))
n <- length(dat$firstName)

vals <- list()
for (i in 1:n) {
    fname <- dat$firstName[i]
    age <- dat$age[i]
    index <- which(fname == dat$firstName &
     (age > dat$age - 5) &
     (age < dat$age + 5))
    vals[[i]] <- index
}

vals <- unique(vals)
dat$id <- NA

for (i in 1:length(vals)) {
    dat$id[vals[[i]]] <- i
}
```

Result

```
  firstName age id
1      John  21  1
2      John  24  1
3      Mary  35  2
4       Bob  30  3
5      Mary  20  4
6       Bob  27  3
```

Comment: Your solution breaks down with the addition of just one more John added to the dataframe at age 30.  `dat <- data.frame("firstName" = c("John", "John", "Mary", "Bob", "Mary", "Bob", "John"), "age"= c(21, 24, 35, 30, 20, 27, 30))`

Comment: Not sure why thats happening but adding `dat$id <- NA` before the last loops seems to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `lag` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(firstName) %>%
  arrange(firstName,age) %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(!(age - (lag(age,default = -Inf) ) <= 5)))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   firstName [3]
  firstName   age    id
  <fct>     <dbl> <int>
1 Bob          27     1
2 Bob          30     1
3 John         21     1
4 John         24     1
5 Mary         20     1
6 Mary         35     2
```